# Libvirt: Cannot access CA certificate '/etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem': No such file or directory

Tags: debian, ssl, libvirt

Debian 6, all libvirt packages are installed. The /etc/pki/ directory is missing. What package is responsible for it?

Comment: What are you using that needs this file?

Comment: libvirtd --listen
00:27:48.198: error : remoteCheckCertFile:278 : Cannot access CA certificate '/etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem': No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure on Debian, but on Amazon Linux (CentOS):

```
rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/pki/CA
openssl-1.0.0e-2.16.amzn1.x86_64
openssl-1.0.0e-2.16.amzn1.i686
```

You could also look into a package called 'ca-certificates'

**Edit:**
Following up on your error from the command, it looks like you'll have to [follow the steps here](http://libvirt.org/remote.html#Remote_TLS_CA)

Comment: openssl & ca-certificates are installed.

Comment: I've edited my post with a link to the steps you should follow

Comment: Hope that works - you'll need to fill in the gaps

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me was to follow `@thinice`'s Edit, above, using these steps here:

[Setting up a Certificate Authority (CA)](http://libvirt.org/remote.html#Remote_TLS_CA)

```
certtool --generate-privkey > cakey.pem
cat > ca.info <<EOF
cn ACME Organization, Inc.
ca
cert_signing_key
EOF
certtool --generate-self-signed --load-privkey cakey.pem \
  --template ca.info --outfile cacert.pem
cp cacert.pem /etc/pki/CA/
```